# Mensaje si se da una condición

Tags: r

Parto de unos datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = '
fecha       edad
01/05/2020  20
02/01/2019  33
03/05/2017  19
04/05/2018  3
09/05/2020  25
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


datos$fecha <- as.Date(datos$fecha, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Quiero comparar la fecha de los datos con una fecha de referencia.

```
fecha_referencia <- as.Date("25/11/2019", format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Quiero que me avise si hay una fecha menor al de referencia.
Algo así como

```
ifelse (datos$fecha < fecha_referencia , "Menor a la fecha","Mayor a la fecha")
```

Pero esto da 5 mensajes, uno por caso. Busco que avise una sola vez. En plan:

"Hay fechas anteriores a la de referencia, son las que están en la posición"

```
which(datos$fecha < fecha_referencia)
```

o si no hubiera ninguna:

"Todas las fechas son posteriores a la fecha de referencia"

Lo que busco es que el mensaje solo salga una vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos condiciones posibles: o la lista de valores menores es nula o tienes 1 o más valores menores al de referencia, en este último caso habría que mostrar una "concatenación" y no los valores por separado.

```
menores <- which(datos$fecha < fecha_referencia)
if (length(menores)==0) {
  "Todas las fechas son posteriores a la fecha de referencia"
} else {
  paste("Hay fechas anteriores a la de referencia, son las que están en la posición", 
        paste(menores, collapse=','))
}
```

No es mala política asegurarse un limite máximo cuando uno traslada un conjunto de valores "verticales" a uno solo "horizontal":

```
  paste("Hay fechas anteriores a la de referencia, las primeras 1000 son las que están en la posición", 
        paste(head(menores,1000), collapse=','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera que se me ocurre es guardar el which en una variable por ejemplo "check", el cual contiene las posiciones que cumplen la condicion

```
check = which(datos$fecha < fecha_referencia)
```

Luego concatenar las filas en un vector de longitud 1, para que el mensaje aparezca una sola vez

```
posiciones = capture.output(cat(check, sep = ", "))
```

Finalmente arrojar el mensaje:

```
ifelse(
  length(check) == 0,
  "Todas las fechas son posteriores a la fecha de referencia",
  paste("Hay fechas anteriores a las de referencia, son las que están en la posiciónes",posiciones)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando el excelente consejo de Patricio, puedes crear una función a todo evento (incluyendo las fechas iguales). El argumento `limite` determinará la cantidad de fechas a imprimir para cada condición.

```
analizadorFecha <- function(x,y,limite = 100){
  mayor <- x > y
  igual <- x == y
  menor <- x < y
  mayor_ <- ''
  igual_ <- ''
  menor_ <- ''
  if(sum(mayor)>0){
    if(sum(mayor)>1){
      mayor_ <- paste0('Hay fechas mayores, estas son ',paste0(head(x[mayor],limite),collapse = ', '),'.\n')
    }else{
      mayor_ <- paste0('Hay una fecha mayor, esta es ',x[mayor],'.\n')
    }
  }
  if(sum(igual)>0){
    if(sum(igual)>1){
      igual_ <- paste0('Hay fechas iguales, estas son ',paste0(head(x[igual],limite),collapse = ', '),'.\n')
    }else{
      igual_ <- paste0('Hay una fecha igual, esta es ',x[igual],'.\n')
    }
  }
  if(sum(menor)>0){
    if(sum(menor)>1){
      igual_ <- paste0('Hay fechas menores, estas son ',paste0(head(x[menor],limite),collapse = ', '),'.\n')
    }else{
      igual_ <- paste0('Hay una fecha menor, esta es ',x[menor],'.\n')
    }
  }
  cat(paste0(mayor_,igual_,menor_))
}

analizadorFecha(x = datos$fecha,y = fecha_referencia)
# Hay fechas mayores, estas son 2020-05-01, 2020-05-09.
# Hay fechas menores, estas son 2019-01-02, 2017-05-03, 2018-05-04.
```

Comment: Genial todo!!!!